# Lost zero number when appendRow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, formatting

When I use `appendRow` in Google Sheets, I lose the leading zero (when my data is a 'phone number), how can I keep it?

I tried `getDataRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@')` before append but this did not work.

```
var rowdata = ["dinh","loc","09182734756"]
ws.appendRow(rowdata );
```

Here's an image of my current result:

[image: result image]

Comment: If you want to put the value of ``09182734756`` using ``appendRow()``, how about modifying from ``var rowdata = ["dinh","loc","09182734756"]`` to ``var rowdata = ["dinh","loc","'09182734756"]``? At Spreadsheet, when ``'`` is added to the top letter, the value is used as a string.

Comment: Tanaike, Tks you so much. I have try and successful but any other way ?

Comment: I discovered a problem in cell add ' before number so wrong i just want keep zero number. result in cell --> ('09182734756) but i want only (09182734756)

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, how about modifying the format of cell to the string type?

Comment: I don't know i try getDataRange().setNumberFormat('@STRING@') before append but not run ... still lost zero number !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `setNumberFormat()` works fine, but you need to apply it via `setNumberFormat('@')` or `setNumberFormats([['@']])` (depends on whether you want to set it on one cell or on a custom `Range`).

Please, remember to set number formats *before* setting values to the target `Range`.

```
function testZero() {  
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var v = ["dinh","loc","09182734756"]; //do not add the "'";

  sh.appendRow(['']); //no need to do this step, it's an example;

  var rng = sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,1,1,v.length);
      rng.setNumberFormats([['@','@','@']]); //for test simplicity, set on Range you need to be of 0\d* pattern;
      rng.setValues([v]);

}
```

UPD: credit goes to Tanaike - a  more flexible (and less heavy) solution to accessing the last column needed is via the values `Array` length.

Comment: I think that the following modification might be required. 1. ``SpreadSheetApp.getActiveSheet()`` to ``SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()``. 2. ``var rng = r.getRange(r.getLastRow(),1,1,r.getLastColumn())`` to ``var rng = r.getRange(r.getLastRow()+1,1,1,v.length)``

Comment: yes, tks you use setValues it run well ! use append maybe change value shoud be use setvalue

Comment: Glad we could help! Could you please clarify the second part of your comment, I am not sure I understand it?